# MDX - include both empty and non empty

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have an mdx query that I'm using in an SSRS report.  I would like to only return hours that are > 50, but I would like to display all years regardless of whether there is data for that year.  I can get the > 50 filter to work, but then I lose the years where there is no data.  I have tried putting the years on the "Pages" axis which then returns all years, but my rows axis no longer respects the filter when I do this.  I've also tried putting the years dimension outside of the NONEMPTY clause, but again it does not respect the > 50 hours filter.
Here is a sample of what I've got so far:

```
SELECT 
  [measures].[Hours] ON COLUMNS
 ,
    [Date].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS
  * 
    {
      Filter
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          CrossJoin
          (
            [Client].[Client].[Client].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[Department].[Department].[Department].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[Title].[Title].[Title].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[Person].[Person].[Person].ALLMEMBERS
          )
         ,[Measures].[Billable Hours]
        )
       ,
        [Measures].[Billable Hours] >= 50
      )
    } ON ROWS
FROM TestCube;
```

Desired result would be to still show the 2017 column even if there is no data, and only show hours > 50 for the columns that have data.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.  I did find a way around it by creating a calculated member that checks for hours > 50, otherwise returns null.  Just wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks,
Hillary

Comment: what would the results look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding `OR ISEMPTY([Measures].[Billable Hours])` into the filter condition:

```
SELECT 
  [measures].[Hours] ON COLUMNS
 ,
    [Date].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS
  * 
    {
      Filter
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          CrossJoin
          (
            [Client].[Client].[Client].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[Department].[Department].[Department].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[Title].[Title].[Title].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[Person].[Person].[Person].ALLMEMBERS
          )
         ,[Measures].[Billable Hours]
        )
       ,
        [Measures].[Billable Hours] >= 50
            OR ISEMPTY([Measures].[Billable Hours])
      )
    } ON ROWS
FROM TestCube;
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I didn't realize I could use the OR function.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the algorithm into a calculated measure. It's faster. The filter function is slow.

```
with
Member [Measures].[Billable Hours 50More] as
IIF([Measures].[Billable Hours] >= 50, [Measures].[Hours], NULL)    

select 
[Measures].[Billable Hours 50More] on 0,
[Date].[Year].[Year].AllMembers * NonEmpty([Client].[Client].[Client].AllMembers * [Department].[Department].[Department].AllMembers * [Title].[Title].[Title].AllMembers * [Person].[Person].[Person].AllMembers, [Billable Hours 50More]) on 1

from TestCube
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is actually what I ended up with.  Much appreciated!